# How to use Highcharts Gantt chart in angular?

Tags: angular, highcharts, gantt-chart, angular2-highcharts

Highcharts Gantt is currently in Alpha but we can use it with this [link](https://github.highcharts.com/gantt/highcharts-gantt.src.js)

I'd like to use this library in a angular project but I have not found any documation to help me in this direction. Is it possible? If so, what is the procedure?

In the case that it would not be possible yet, is there any other angular library for Gantt Chart?

Comment: Easiest solution would be to just include that javascript file as an asset, and then require('filelocation')(HighCharts) similar to other library inclusions.

Comment: Would it be possible to import it as a module instead?

Comment: If you by module you mean Highcharts module, then no. Highcharts Gantt is not a module for Highcharts - it's a separate product. It's not yet published, so it doesn't have an official NPM package. You could load the JS code as *Z. Bagley* suggested.

Comment: any update about the use of GanttChart ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This Procedure is specifically for Angular and highcharts gantt

1. Install Highcharts from NPM using "npm install --save highchats" command for latest version
2. Create component for chart

in component.ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef, AfterViewInit, AfterViewChecked } from '@angular/core';
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts/highcharts-gantt';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-chart',
  templateUrl: './chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chart.component.scss']
})
export class ChartComponent implements OnInit,AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('divRef', { static: false }) divReference: ElementRef;
  constructor() { }
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.highchartclick();
 }
ngOnInit(): void {

}
  highchartclick() {
    Highcharts.ganttChart(this.divReference.nativeElement as HTMLElement, {
      title: {
        text: 'Simple Gantt Chart'
      },
      chart: { renderTo: this.divReference.nativeElement as HTMLElement },
      series: [
        {
          name: 'Project 1',
          type: 'gantt',
          data: [
            {
              id: 's',
              name: 'Start prototype',
              start: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 20),
              end: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 20)
            }, {
              id: 'b',
              name: 'Develop',
              start: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 20),
              end: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 25),
              dependency: 's'
            }, {
              id: 'a',
              name: 'Run acceptance tests',
              start: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 23),
              end: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 26)
            },
            {
              name: 'Test prototype',
              start: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 24),
              end: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 29),
              dependency: ['a', 'b']
            }
          ]
        }]
    });
  }
}
```

in component .html file

```
<div id="container" #divRef  ></div>
```

Hope this will help others it is working fine in angular 10 and highchart version 8.1.2

Comment: you can remove the `@ViewChild` and use `Highcharts.ganttChart('container', { ... });` instead (where `container` is the id of the div)